# Handle different set of extra arguments in the formatting of logging calls

Tags: python, logging

I want to enable callers of my loggers to pass any (or no) collection of "extra" values to my logger and want to format these in a consistent way.

To use the normal formatting strings of the logging module I seem to have to know which key, value pairs are going to be included in the `extra` dictionary beforehand. My main question is how to handle different set of extra key, value pairs by different callers.

For example the following logger calls:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.warn("Test Message 1", extra={"state_id": 1, "country_id": 2, "city_id": 3})
logger.warn("Test Message 2", extra={"city_id": 3, "state_id": 1})
logger.warn("Test Message 3")
```

I want to come out as:

"WARNING: Test Message 1 {city_id: 3, country_id: 2, state_id:1}"

"WARNING: Test Message 2 {city_id: 3, state_id:1}"

"WARNING: Test Message 3"

Also I have a few technical restrictions:

1. Except for the "standard" text output I also export the logging records as json-logs in which the different ids are included, and the message field should only contain the original message. Therefore I cant just append these values to the message itself.
2. I dont control the client code, so I cant change the way the logger is called.
3. Since I have may different loggers which share the same formatter / handler I would prefer some solution at the formatter / handler level that would work for all different loggers.

Comment: What is your question? Why don't you write some code that does what you want?

Comment: The question is how I can get the logging calls to come out formatted in the way as specified above. (Maybe some custom formatter). The problem is that with the normal formatting strings you have to know beforehand which key,value pairs are included in the extras dictionary.

Comment: Checkout the format argument to the logger: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.format

Comment: I looked at the different ways of specifying the format argument and for any specific set of extra arguments it would be quite straightforward but I wasnt able to find out how to handle this problem of not knowing which extra arguments will be passed.